# Default Object Parameter in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi-generator

I don't understand default values for object parameters in swagger. The documentation doesn't seem to have any examples.

For example:

```
components:
  parameters:
    coordinates:
      in: query
      name: coordinates
      description: Test Obj Parameter
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          lat:
            type: number
            default: 0.0
          long:
            type: number
            default: 0.0
      required: false

paths:
  /my/path/:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: "./common.yaml#/components/parameters/coordinates"
```

1. I assume I can define `default: [51.47, 0.0]` in the path's parameters section?
2. If all member fields are optional, and the parameter itself is optional, do I need to specify a default value in the path's parameters? If I don't and the user calls the endpoint without providing a value would the back end get the coordinates 0, 0 ?

The code that's generated with `default: [51.47, 0.0]` , `default: {"lat":51.4, "lon":0.0}` and with no default specified is the same.

Making  one of the member fields required seems to only add a isSet flag, setteng and unsetter functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different questions here, so I'm going to split them up into three topics

1. Where can I find an example of a valid schema with parameters that define default values?
2. Can I define the default values in the path's parameters section?
3. If parameters and member fields are optional, does the default value need to be declared?

*Disclaimer:  You didn't provide any generator commands, so I am using the gradle-plugin with the `spring` generator for most of my examples.  I can update this to use a different plugin or generator if you are unable to get your code working with what I provide.*

## Where can I find examples?

The [swagger documentation for parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) has a section called Default Parameter Values.  In that section, the documentation states

> "Use the default keyword in the parameter schema to specify the default value for an optional parameter. The default value is the one that the server uses if the client does not supply the parameter value in the request. The value type must be the same as the parameter’s data type."

It also has the following example:

```yaml
 parameters:
        - in: query
          name: offset
          schema:
            type: integer
            minimum: 0
            default: 0
          required: false
          description: The number of items to skip before starting to collect the result set.
        - in: query
          name: limit
          schema:
            type: integer
            minimum: 1
            maximum: 100
            default: 20
          required: false
          description: The number of items to return.
```

The coordinates schema you provided in your question is a valid schema.  I even went so far as to test it in my own generator, using the `spring` generator, and I was able to get a valid object created.  This object had the below fields defined:

```java
@JsonProperty("lat")
private BigDecimal lat = new BigDecimal("0.0");

@JsonProperty("long")
private BigDecimal _long = new BigDecimal("0.0");
```

As you can see, the default values were defined as expected.

## Can I define the default values in the path's parameters section?

Plainly speaking, no.  The [swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) states:

> Any sibling elements of a $ref are ignored. This is because $ref works by replacing itself and everything on its level with the definition it is pointing at.

Consider the following schema:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    EmployeeInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          description: an employee's name
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Name'
        address:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Address'
          description: an employee's address
    CustomerInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          description: a customer's name
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Name'
        address:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Address'
          description: a customer's address
    Name:
      description: a standard name
      type: object
      properties:
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
    Address:
      description: a standard address
      type: object
      properties:
        street:
          type: string
        city:
          type: string
        state:
          type: string
        zip:
          type: string
```

This schema appears valid, and will pass most validation tools.  However, if we look at the employee info object in our swagger-ui, we will see that the descriptions for the name and address ignore the description in the schema.
[image: Swagger ui image]

This is because, as the documentation states, anything else contained at the same level as the `$ref` is ignored.

The same is true for any defaults you try to set at the path level.  If you are referencing a schema contained elsewhere, than the default values will be ignored.

## Do I have to declare a default value?

This is more of a style choice, and falls back to the age old answer:  "it depends".  Remember that swagger-ui is in part a REST interface, but is also your documentation.  What are you doing with these coordinates?  What happens if the users don't supply them?  What is expected to happen?  Does providing them or not providing them change your APIs response schema?

Most importantly, do you want your users to know of the coordinates default values?

For example, you can easily add a method in your controller that sets the values to something if they are not provided in the request.  You don't have to tell your users about this.  This would be a default value without documentation.  If you want to tell your users about it, you can set an example and a description that explains the default value.

If the value is required, I personally prefer to make the users provide it.  This ensures they know what they are requesting and what they are getting.  If the value is optional, it all comes down to style and documentation.  I prefer explaining the usage to my users, so I will document the default so they are aware of how it is being used.  This will also result in fields being set automatically, such as in the Java code above.

---

## Updated to show use of examples instead of default values

Here's a yaml using examples in parameters.  You can copy and paste it into [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) to see how it renders and displays.  When choosing an example to view, notice that the description changes.  Also notice that when you click try it out, it will create a request using the example (with the values you have provided in the example:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: My-API
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: 'https://my.server.com'
paths:
  /employees:
    get:
      tags:
        - Employees
      summary: Add a new article to the store
      description: Get an Object
      operationId: getObject
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/employeeInfo'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
components:
  parameters:
    employeeInfo:
      name: employee
      in: query
      description: The information of the employee
      required: false
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/EmployeeInfo'
      examples:
        Employee Information:
          value:
            name: Bob Smith
            title: Front Desk
            responsibilities:
              - working
              - playing
            phone: (123) 555-1234
          description: |
            This is a description of the manager item.
            you can explain default values here.
            
            For example:
            
            **Parameters**:
            * **title**: 
              * defaults to Night Manager if not provided
              * Any String is valid, but may return status 404 if the title is not a valid title after validation
            * **name**:
              * no default value

        Manager Information:
          value:
            name: Kevin Mitchell
            title: Night Manager
            responsibilities:
              - watch Bob
              - don't sleep
          description: |
            This is a description of the manager item.
            you can explain default values here.
            
            For example:
            
            **Parameters**:
            * **title**: 
              * defaults to Night Manager if not provided
              * Any String is valid, but may return status 404 if the title is not a valid title after validation
            * **name**:
              * no default value
              * must be a valid employee name

  schemas:
    EmployeeInfo:
      description: general employee information
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        phone:
          type: string
          pattern: '^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$'
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ManagementInfo'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/GruntInfo'
        
    GruntInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        responsibilities:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/EmployeeResponsibilities'
    ManagementInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          default: Bob
        title:
          type: string
          default: Manager
        responsibilities:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ManagerResponsibilities'
    ManagerResponsibilities:
      description: manager responsibilities
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - Meetings
          - Sleeping
          - Planning
          - Rehersing
          - Supervising
      default:
        - meetings
        - sleeping
    EmployeeResponsibilities:
      title: Employee Responsibilities
      description: Employee responsibilities
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - cleaning
          - organizing
          - attending
      default:
        - cleaning
```

You can now see that each example is available in the drop-down, along with the description of the values.

[image: Examples with descriptions]

If you click try it out on the employee example, it will create the following request:
`https://my.server.com/employees?name=Bob%20Smith&title=Front%20Desk&responsibilities=working&responsibilities=playing&phone=%28123%29%20555-1234`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is very helpful. I did look at the examples in the documentation but they were all showing atomic types, not classes.

Comment: $ref resulting in siblings to be ignored would be a problem. $refs are useful to reuse the model objects in multiple places, but it's possible that I would want to have different default values depending on the endpoint. Is there any way around that short of in-lining the definition?

Comment: Finally, what's the correct syntax for defining default values for complex types? Can I just supply yaml / JSON in the "default" field?

Comment: @ventsyv Unfortunately, there is no way to redefine a model as you reference it.  You would need to reuse/redefine the model with different properties.  In my above example, you could create an `EmployeeAddress` and a `CustomerAddress` object, each with different descriptions.  The same would be true for parameters.  As for the syntax, no, you cannot supply a yaml in the default field.  The default field is specific to each field.  Don't get to hung-up on the default.  This is what the description is for.  You can supply your own defaults in your code implementation.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: After consideration of your question, I've come to the conclusion that you are looking for default values for your users, not backend implementations.  You shouldn't use default values in this manner.  Use examples instead.  I've added an example to the answer.